# URL's generated with TomEE are not working

Tags: java, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I created a basic app to return "hello world" when going to a url, in my case `http://localhost:8080/hello`. When I go to said URL with the application running I receive a 404 as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4WIN.png). I've setup the URL in the TomEE tab of the Intelij IDEA. So far I've tried a lot of different TomEE versions and changing the target URL without much luck. I was hoping perhaps someone here might know something that might help.

I haven't made many posts here before, but I've tried to be as complete as possible if there is anything missing please let me know and I'll add it to the post, thanks so much for taking a look!

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHelloWorld() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

[TomEE server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0759e.png)
[TomEE deployment settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6cKo.png)

Comment: You should have somewhere application class like `@ApplicationPath("restPath")
public class MyRestApplication extends Application ` . And then your path to resource would be in form: ` http://localhost:8080/war-context/restPath/hello`  Maybe switch to OpenLiberty , here is nice guide - https://openliberty.io/guides/rest-intro.html